Permissions starting with "advance" in Guidewire's PolicyCenter
I'm trying to find information on 9 permissions in Guidewire's PolicyCenter. I.e. advanceaudit, advancecancellation, advanceissuance, advancepolchange, advancereinstate, advancerenewal, advancerewrite, advancerewrnewacct and advancesubmission.
I already looked in the documentation and Guidewire's forum, but couldn't find any information.
I also tried to find out by looking in the code, but with no result.
Lastly I tested if a user without them will be able to create a submission, quote and issue a policy and it turned out that it was possible.
Does anyone know what a user that doesn't have them will not be able to do in the system?

I did a cursory look at the documentation to make sure I understood the meaning of "advance" in this context. I could be slightly off on some of my assumptions. I hope this information helps and I will edit my answer if someone corrects me in the comments.
"Advance" in this context means advancing a job (submission, renewal, etc) to the next stage of the job (start quote, bind, issue, etc). In the JobProcess.gs class you will notice calls to JobConditions.checkAdvancePermission() which does eventually check to see if the user has the advance permission for the job type they are working on. For a producer who is Active I believe the advance permissions are automatically available. See the link below (login required) and the section I copied below. If you were testing with an Active producer then that use likely would not have needed that permission specified.
https://docs.guidewire.com/self-managed/pc/1023/app/app/pc/topics/c_bn4581559.html

Both the status of the matching producer code and the status of the user’s organization must be checked before allowing access through producer code security. Both status fields must either be Active or on the list of allowed status values in the permission handler. Without any configuration to the security handlers, full permissions are granted when the status is Active. No permissions are allowed if the status is anything else, except for renewals, which allow for Limited status.

You will also notice in the security-config.xml that the advance permission is explicitly granted to producers having a Limited status for most of the job types. From the security-config.xml:
<JobProducerCodeHandler jobType="Renewal" permKey="advance" desc="Permission to advance a renewal">
  <SystemPermType code="advancerenewal"/>
  <ProducerStatus code="Limited"/>
</JobProducerCodeHandler>

<JobProducerCodeHandler jobType="PolicyChange" permKey="advance" desc="Permission to advance a policy change">
  <SystemPermType code="advancepolchange"/>
  <ProducerStatus code="Limited"/>
</JobProducerCodeHandler>

So the JobProducerCodeHandler above means that a producer with a Limited status could also advance a renewal job in addition to Active producers. A producer in Terminated, Terminating, or Suspended status could not advance a renewal.
Maybe try creating a submission with a suspended producer and see if PolicyCenter blocks this action.

Thank you for your answer. I tested it and users that have the advance permissions can bypass the blocking of no transactions on an account with inactive producer code associated with it. I marked you answer as solution.
